# How to change the login mode of local SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

How to change the login mode of the existing local `MDF database file` from `Windows` authentication mode to `Sql server` authentication mode?

What should the connection string be modified to after the mode is modified to use Sql Server authentication ?

Comment: Take a look at the following link: [Change Server Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change authentication mode using SSMS by the help of the following link: [Change Server Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Change the ConnectionStringas as follow in the link: [SQL Server Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)